# Way to download all attachments from yahoo.com

Tags: list-manipulation, export, import, syntax, code-request

For a long time now I want to download the attachments from my yahoo.con mail, only the files, no text, but in batches, so MMA gets into my mail and downloads every attached file it finds in a folder.

I have looked in the forum and in the MMA help, but I can't find something that works for me, can you help me

Comment: A Google search for automate download all email attachments finds lots of people describing how to do that. Putting Mathematica in front of that query gets a few extra responses, but none that I saw seem to suggest how to use MMA to do that. Maybe you could read some of the non-MMA methods and see if you could twist MMA into doing that. AutoHotKey or Power Automate seem like the popular way to do this.